# Using orthophotos as basemap in CartoDB?

Tags: arcmap, carto, orthophoto

I have seen a java example of how to use a raster overlay in CartoDB, but what about replacing the basemap entirely with orthophotos?

In the web GUI for selecting basemap there is an option for the users imagery, but I can't seem to get it working and when I try to upload a TIFF to my datasets I get a "file too large" error.  I think I am supposed to create a Mapbox account and upload the TIFFs there and then point to them from CartoDB?

I guess I am looking for a step-by-step walk through of how to accomplish going from an orthophoto mosaic in ArcMap to exporting it out for use in Mapbox, putting it there, and then pointing to it in CartoDB (which seems to be the easy part).

Answer (score 1):

You can put any WMS/TMS and MapBox layers as a basemap on any CartoDB Map using the built in custom base maps dialog. Using CartoDB.js you have even more flexibility since you can provide any valid Leaflet layer and then put your map on top using the `createLayer` method (example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/4ab8cdef2b42c5f651c7) using a WMS).

Uploading TIFF files to CartoDB is possible but not meant at all to serve orthoimagery. PostGIS Raster is supposed to be used to analyze data more than to store RBG images. So your procedure as you guessed is uploading your imagery somewhere (probably a tiled service) and then use it as a basemap.

Comment: So then do you have a walkthrough for getting a mosaic out of Arcmap and into Mapbox tiles?  Is Tilemill still the route or do I have to use the Mapbox studio web interface?  Can I use a mosaic or do i have to convert individual rasters?

Comment: Nope sorry, I gave you all I had. Haven't used ArcMap for more than ten years. Can't say about MapBox Studio either, never used it with raster files but I'm sure you can check their usually awesome documentation.